# How to add a constraint on all the columns of a table in a single query?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, unique

I have a database named dbapp. I need to add the constraint 'NOT NULL' to all the columns of all the tables in this database. I am unable to form this query. Even if I am able to perform it individually on each table, it would be fine. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a trivial task. But you may try -

- Read information from `information_schema.columns` table
- Generate ALTER TABLE statements for each table

Note, that you should take into consideration all field properties, not only NULL/NOT NULL.

Another variant is to edit fields one by one, using one of the MySQL GUI tools.

Comment: How do I exactly **generate** ALTER TABLE Queries? Can you give me the proper syntax for _generating_ it?

Comment: You could write an application to generate ALTER TABLE statememts. This application has to read/analyze MySQL matadata, and build statements. The syntax is here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html.